# function should return array but returns NULL instead

Tags: php

I have this function that should return an array, but it returns NULL instead. I think it might have to do with the size of the array it generates, because sometimes it does work properly. I have tried to do a var_dump before the return, which always showed the array I needed, however a var_dump of the output of the function just shows NULL.

```
function getAllUploads($videoFeed, $videos = array(), $counter = 1){
    foreach($videoFeed as $videoEntry){
        if($videoEntry->extensionElements[6]->extensionAttributes['permission']['value'] == "allowed"){
            $videos[] = array("videoID" => $videoEntry->getVideoId(), "uploaded" => ytToMySQLDateTime($videoEntry->getPublished()->getText())); //date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $videoEntry->getPublished()->getText())
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    try{
        $videoFeed = $videoFeed->getNextFeed();
    }catch(Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e){
        return $videos;
    }

    if($videoFeed){
        getAllUploads($videoFeed, $videos, $counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This function does not return anything unless a `Zend_Gdata_App_Exception` is thrown.

Comment: No return is last line? Seems troublesome....

Comment: Yea, I know. But the exception should always be thrown eventually. Still I'll try returning some where else as well..

Comment: If the exception is supposed to be thrown some time during the recursion, the answer below is correct as you need to `return` the value the recursion gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the function inside the last `if()` statement

```
function getAllUploads($videoFeed, $videos = array(), $counter = 1){
    foreach($videoFeed as $videoEntry){
        if($videoEntry->extensionElements[6]->extensionAttributes['permission']['value'] == "allowed"){
            $videos[] = array("videoID" => $videoEntry->getVideoId(), "uploaded" => ytToMySQLDateTime($videoEntry->getPublished()->getText())); //date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $videoEntry->getPublished()->getText())
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    try{
        $videoFeed = $videoFeed->getNextFeed();
    }catch(Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e){
        return $videos;
    }

    if($videoFeed){
        return getAllUploads($videoFeed, $videos, $counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you even loose the last 'if'? Otherwise you need another return.

Comment: Well the `catch` does the other return, if it doesn't catch the `if($videoFeed)` will return